# In Notepad++ search for a string and newline

Tags: notepad++

I have following strings in the test text files:

```
123
abc \
456
def
```

I would like to search for  `\` + newline in Notepad++ within all .txt files in a particular folder. So something like  `\ \n\r`.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this in Notepad++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may search for the following pattern:

```regex
[ ]\\\R
```

Explanation:

```regex
[ ]  find a space character
\\   find a literal backslash character
\R   find a device independent newline
```

Note that `\R` will match the same thing as `\r?\n`, which covers both Linux and Windows line endings (depending on your actual system).